# Exporting python list to an environment variable using OS library

Tags: python, scripting, python-os

Let's say I have a list

```
someList = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and I would like to use

```
os.environ["someList"] = someList
```

to store the list as an environment variable.

I am currently getting an error, is there a way to do this?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: i get the typerror  str expected, not list

Comment: Environment variables can only be strings.  If you want to store something that isn't a string in an environment variable you need some consistent way of serializing and deserializing it to/from a string, and there is no one standard for doing so.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the list? Are you saving it for later use? Maybe you should try pickle?

Comment: This looks like a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing data structures via environment variables is an odd thing to do.
As the error is telling you, environment variables must be strings.

If you really have a need to do this, one simple solution is to convert the list to a json string, store it in the environment variable, and then have the child process convert it back to a python list.

For example, to encode the data as a string using json:

```
import json, os
os.environ['someList'] = json.dumps(["a", "b", "c"])
```

Then, to reconstitute the data you do the reverse:

```
import json, os
data = json.loads(os.environ['someList'])
```

Of course, this will only work on simple objects that can be safely encoded to json.

Comment: is there a example i can refer to maybe? I'm not familiar with json string and child process

Comment: @Ryguy444222 Example of what? You can find plenty of resources on JSON online.